# how to make a test case to check the value of counter will not be less than zero even if decrement button is pressed

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, jestjs, enzyme

counter.js

```
import React from "react";

export default function Counter() {
  const [counter , setCouter]  = React.useState(0);
  return (
    <div className="App">
     <h1>This is Counter App of me</h1>
     <div id="counter-value">{counter}</div>
     <button id="increment-btn" onClick={() => setCouter(counter + 1)}>Increment</button>
     <button id="decrement-btn" onClick={() => setCouter(counter > 0 ? counter - 1 : 0)}>Decrement</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

app.js

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";
import Counter from "./Counter";

function App() {
 
  return (
    <div className="App">
    <Counter/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

app.test.js

```
import React from "react";
import { mount } from "enzyme";
import App from "./App";
import Counter from "./Counter"
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';

describe("Counter Testing", () => {
  let wrapper;
  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = mount(<App/>)
  })


test("render the click event of decrement button of and check the counter value cannot be less than 0" , () => {
  if(wrapper.find("#counter-value").text() === "0"){
     wrapper.find("#decrement-btn").simulate("click")
   expect(wrapper.find("#counter-value").text()).toBe("0")
  //  expect(wrapper.find("#counter-value").text()).toBeGreaterThanOrEqual(0)
  }
})
});
```

how to write a test case to test that counter value will not be less than 0 even if decrement button is pressed many times without any if condition how to use `toBeGreaterThanOrEqual` here it is expecting a number value but I am getting a string value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[.text() => String](https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/text.html) returns a string **NOT** number.

You don't have to use if condition in your test case.

```js
setCouter(counter > 0 ? counter - 1 : 0)
```

This statement ensures that the `counter` state will not be less than `0`. This is what you are testing. To test this, we can mount the component firstly, the initial state of the `counter` is `0`, and simulate the user clicking the decrease button multiple times and assert that the `counter` state displayed is `0`.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import App from './App';

describe('Counter Testing', () => {
  let wrapper;
  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = mount(<App />);
  });

  test('render the click event of decrement button of and check the counter value cannot be less than 0', () => {
    const decrementButton = wrapper.find('#decrement-btn');
    decrementButton.simulate('click');
    decrementButton.simulate('click');
    expect(wrapper.find('#counter-value').text()).toBe('0');
  });
});
```

Test result:

```
 PASS  examples/70112961/app.test.js (10.102 s)
  Counter Testing
    ✓ render the click event of decrement button of and check the counter value cannot be less than 0 (40 ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        11.088 s, estimated 12 s
```